# Adding multiple textbox automatically without button in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, addition

I have created a table and added textbox in it.
I had Use auto post back property with formula to add column 1(ratetexbox) + column 2(QTYtexbox) = column 3,now how to add the total of column 3 in a total.textbox

will adding column 1 + column 2 in column 3 I described a public void  addition() and wrote the formula then in textbox of column 1 and 2 i call it.
Hence i got the result(addition) in column 3 textbox.
now i need to calculate all the 7 textbox in column 3 and add it in total.textbox without using button

```
   public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void Multiply1()
    {
        int ma1, mb1;

        bool isAVaild = int.TryParse(Rate1.Text, out ma1);
        bool isBVaild = int.TryParse(Qty1.Text , out mb1);

        if (isAVaild && isBVaild  )
            Amount1.Text = (ma1 * mb1  ).ToString();
        else
           Amount1.Text = "";
    }
    protected void Rate1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Multiply1();
    }

    protected void Qty1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Multiply1();
    }
           public void Multiply2()
    {
        int ma2, mb2;

        bool isAVaild = int.TryParse(Rate2.Text, out ma2);
        bool isBVaild = int.TryParse(Qty2.Text, out mb2);

        if (isAVaild && isBVaild)
            Amount2.Text = (ma2 * mb2).ToString();
        else
            Amount2.Text = "";
    }
    protected void Rate2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Multiply2();
    }
           public void TotalAmount()
    {
        int t1,t2 ;

        bool isAVaild = int.TryParse(Amount1.Text , out t1);
        bool isBVaild = int.TryParse(Amount2.Text , out t2);
        //bool isCVaild = int.TryParse(Amount3.Text, out t3);
        //bool isDVaild = int.TryParse(Amount4.Text, out t4);
        //bool isEVaild = int.TryParse(Amount5.Text, out t5);
        //bool isFVaild = int.TryParse(Amount6.Text, out t6);
        //bool isGVaild = int.TryParse(Amount7.Text, out t7);
        if (isAVaild && isBVaild )
            //&& isCVaild && isDVaild && isFVaild && isGVaild )
            Totalamount.Text  = (t1 + t2 ).ToString();
        else
            Totalamount.Text = "";
    }

    protected void Amount1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TotalAmount();
    }

    protected void Amount2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TotalAmount();
    }
```

I expected to see the output but it is not showing anything
please help me anyone

Comment: Is the Page_Load method really empty or did you omit some code there?

Comment: it is empty currently but i will add code for later for a differnet thing related to dropdown list

Comment: Are you sure the events are bound to the controls?

Comment: can you specify cause actually i am not much of a coder an knows only basic among basic(maybe not even that)